# In splunk is there a way to prepopulate the time input field with values for another token?

Tags: splunk, splunk-dashboard

In Splunk, I have a dashboard with init-section.  I use the init-section to set 2 tokens, then I use the token values to set the default value for a time input.

When I run the dashboard, the time input is unpopulated.  If I replace $earliest_time_token$, $latest_time_token$ with their actual values then the time token is pre-populated.

Is there a way to pre-populate the time input field using variables?

---

fyi - I tried -7d@d & "-7d@d" I get the same result

---

```
<form>
  <init>
    <set token="earliest_time_token">"-7d@d"</set>
    <set token="latest_time_token">"now"</set>
  </init>
  <label>Time Input</label>
  <fieldset autoRun="true" submitButton="false">
    <input type="time" token="time_token" searchWhenChanged="true">
      <label>Time Range</label>
      <default>
        <earliest>$earliest_time_token$</earliest>
        <latest>$latest_time_token$</latest>
      </default>
    </input>
    ....
  </fieldset>
  ....
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this to work by directly setting the earliest and latest values of the time range picker. While that is not exactly what you asked for, it does achieve what you want to achieve:

```
<form>
  <init>
    <set token="form.time_token.earliest">-7d@d</set>
    <set token="form.time_token.latest">now</set>
  </init>
  <label>Time Input</label>
  <fieldset autoRun="true" submitButton="false">
    <input type="time" token="time_token" searchWhenChanged="true">
      <label>Time Range</label>
    </input>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

I have tested this and it works. It also recognizes this a standard time range, so it will display it nicely on the time range picker (instead of showing "Custom time range").